# Set static colors on a Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, linechart, google-visualization

I'm trying to set static colors on a line Chart depending on the column label.

For example, if I have 3 columns in my dataview :

(Index -> Column Label)

0 -> Foo

1 -> Bar

2 -> Zoo

When I set the color white for the column "0" (in my chart wrapper's options), and if I redraw my chart like this :

0 -> Bar

1 -> Zoo

The column "Bar" will be white instead of "Foo" (which is not in the dataview anymore).

I would like each column label (and so each line on the chart) to keep its original color. Can someone help me please ? 
Thank you guys by advance for helping me :).

**EDIT** : Here is the code of my Chart Wrapper.

```
 `var cont_inter_typeJetWeb = '../Controleur/CONT_dataGraphTypeJetWeb.php?before='+p_before_start+'&now='+p_now_start;
 var jsonDataTypeJetWeb = $.ajax({
  url: cont_inter_typeJetWeb,
  dataType: "json",
  async: false
  }).responseText;

 var dataTypeJetWeb = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonDataTypeJetWeb);

 var dashboardTypeJetWeb = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_typeJetWeb_div'));

 var typeJetWebRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'filter_typeJetWeb_div',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Date'
      }
  });

 var viewTypeJetWeb = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTypeJetWeb);

 create_choice();

 viewTypeJetWeb.setRows(viewTypeJetWeb.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, minValue: date_before, maxValue: date_now}]));

 var typeJetWebWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'LineChart',
  dataTable: viewTypeJetWeb,
  options: {'title':'Webposts by Owners',
               'width':1150,
               'height':300,
               'backgroundColor':'#e0e0e0',
               'chartArea':{'width':'100%', 'left':'5%'},
                'legend': 'none'
              },
  containerId: 'typeJetWeb_div'
});

dashboardTypeJetWeb.bind(typeJetWebRangeSlider, typeJetWebWrapper);
dashboardTypeJetWeb.draw(viewTypeJetWeb);`
```

The `create_choice()` function is here to set the columns of my dataview depending on some parameters.

And here is what I have in my event handler in order to re-draw the chart :

```
viewTypeJetWeb = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTypeJetWeb);
mod_choice();

viewTypeJetWeb.setRows(viewTypeJetWeb.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, minValue: date_before, maxValue: date_now}]));


dashboardTypeJetWeb.bind(typeJetWebRangeSlider, typeJetWebWrapper);
dashboardTypeJetWeb.draw(viewTypeJetWeb);
```

When I re-draw the chart, it's the `mod_choice()` function that selects different columns for the new data view.

I would like to set the static colors for the `typeJetWebWrapper`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I added it in my post.

Comment: I have edited it again sorry ^^.

Comment: don't see where you set the `colors`, but using a [`'style'` column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) should work here...

Comment: I don't set the colors here. I tried with the option `series` but this didn't work. I will try the `'style'` column role and tell you if it works. Thank you :).
PS : I just read the documentation and it seems to be exactly what I need !

Comment: Ok, I still have a problem with the syntaxe I think. 
The errors are "a.trim is not a function" & "google-visualization-errors: container is null. message: One or more participants failed to draw()".

Here is the column I added : `{"label":"","type":"string","p":{"role":"style"}}`.

And this is how I call it in my rows : `{"v":"color : red"}`.

Comment: Nervermind, it worked thank you !

Comment: cheers! glad you were able to get it working...

Comment: :) Thank you for your time !

Comment: Can you share the code which worked, Thanks!!